# React App: How to change body css style when switching pages

Tags: reactjs

Lets say on my home page, I have in my index.css

```
body {
   margin-top: 5%;
}
```

And lets say I have another page called AccountSettings page and on the accountsettings.css I have:

```
body {
   margin-top: 8%;
}
```

So when I am switching between pages, I want the body style to change. How do I do this on a react app? Sorry, I am new to react

Comment: You can add style in every component and overwrite the css.

Comment: Change the body style in each component, and remember to add `!important`.

Comment: You can probably just create a wrapper component and change your styles there. body is often outside of the root element, so you don't have to override your styles everywhere